# How can i translate this one into a App.js code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to try translate this index.js into a App.js but I don't have any idea I've try it once but it doesn't show up any text

What code should I change here to make it work in App.js and lessen the populated code in index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

function Anotherwan(props){
  return (
    <div>
    <h1> Time: {props.time.toLocaleTimeString()}</h1>
  </div>
  );
}

class Clock extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {time: new Date()};
  }
  componentDidMount(){
this.TimerID = setInterval(
  () => this.tick(), 1000
);
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.TimerID);
  }

  tick (){
    this.setState({
      time: new Date()
    })
  }
  render (){
 return (
    <Anotherwan time={this.time.date} />
)
}
}
root.render(<Clock />);
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your `index.js` is the only file that is printing stuff on to your screen, everything else you have to `export/import`.
If you are using create-react-app, you will see that `index.js` imports the `<App />` component then renders it.

Your `App.js` is not doing anything other than building and exporting the `<App />` components.

If you are new to React, they have a tutorial and documentations on [site](https://reactjs.org/), you would be able to find a lot more information from them!